# Migrating from SQLAlchemy core to ORM

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Currently we only use SQLAlchemy core, so all the tables are defined using Table. Now, we would like to incrementally port the existing Tables to ORM and have new Tables use ORM from scratch.

As an example, say we currently have

```
Users = Table(
    'users', # Table name
    metadata,
    Column('id', String, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('email_address', String),
)
```

and we'd like to add a Posts table using the ORM, something like

```
class Posts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    contents = Column(String(300))
```

How do I update the Users table to reflect the fact that a user can have multiple Posts ? The intended end goal is to have something like

```
Users = Table(
    'users', # Table name
    metadata,
    Column('id', String, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('email_address', String),

    # How to express the equivalent of this ?
    posts = relationship("Posts", back_populates="submitter")
)

class Posts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    contents = Column(String)
    submitter = relationship("Users", back_populates="posts")
```

Is it possible to do this ? Or will I have to convert the Users table to ORM before doing something like this ?

Comment: `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship()` is for providing relationships between mapped classes, so you wont get lucky with `Table`. You might be able to ease the pain of converting the tables to mapped classes with [automapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html).

Comment: Thanks, Ilja. Automapper would probably work in converting the tables to mapped classes, however this would mean that the migration would be a 'big bang' migration with all of the database access code which currently used Core being rewritten to use ORM. We were hoping that there would be a path to a more gradual migration, but it looks like there isn't :-(